# Does Yajna purify air?

Tags: yajna

When I was a child,  I had read in books that one of the benefits of performing a yajna/yagya/hawan was that it purifies air. Is there any scientific basis to this statement or is it all just a made up fact because if it's true why don't we just do yajna/yagya/hawan to purify the air and as a result reduce the pollution?